# Where will the tokens released on Stellar be stored?

Tags: token, token-wallet

Can you store tokens in any Stellar wallet like erc20 tokens in an Ethereum wallet?

Answer (score 13):

Tokens are "stored" in the ledger not in a wallet. You can use a wallet to manage and transfer them with a better UI.

In stellar terms your tokens are [Assets](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/assets.html). They begin to "exist" on the ledger when somebody trusts the issuer who "created" them by setting a [trustline](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/assets.html#trustlines) first and then they receive a [payment](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/list-of-operations.html#payment) with that asset type.  It's all about trust.

You can find more information about tokens in the [blog](https://www.stellar.org/blog/tokens-on-stellar/).